# Multivariate Regression?

Tags: multivariate-regression

All I know about multivariate regression is that there's multiple outputs.

I'd like to learn more, but I have no idea where to start because all of the tutorials that say 'multivariate regression' are mislabeled and are actually 'multi**variable** regression', which is completely different.

Anyone have any recommendations for a tutorial? Something like youtube or coursera would be ideal, but I couldn't find anything on youtube or coursera